# Outlook 2016: Changing the color of unanswered emails

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2016

I am using Outlook 2016 on windows, I would like to visually identify better (e.g. a color) the emails I have not yet answered or that I have not forwarded.

I found the conditional formatting but I couldn't find any option to identify unanswered or un forwarded mail.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to use colour to identify unprocessed emails, I would:

1. Go to View -> Change View -> <Current view settings> -> Modify -> Columns. I would then add "Categories" to the visible columns.
2. I would use the AddItem event to set the Category for all new emails to red.
3. I would use the MailItem Reply and Forward events to the set the Category to green.

This would give a block of red or green against every email in Inbox.

However, I would not use colour. I would use the MailItem Reply and Forward events to move the item to a different folder named something like "Processed".  With this approach, only the unprocessed emails would remain in Inbox.